# Disabling Windows Mobile taskbar, but enabling camera

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-mobile, camera

I’m writing a Windows Mobile application that disables that hides and disables the Windows taskbar, thereby preventing the user from accessing Windows functionality. However, the application needs to be able to take photos as well, and that’s where the problem begins. When the taskbar is enabled, the other buttons on the device (Home, Capture Photo, Up, Down, etc) are disabled as well. I somehow have to send a message that enables the Capture Photo button, but all my attempts have proven fruitless.

I have also used Visual Studio 2008’s Remote Spy tool to keep track of the messages (and to get the hexadecimal values)

Here is the code I have so far:

`Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms
Imports Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Forms

Public Class BarControl
  <DllImport("coredll.dll", EntryPoint:="GetForegroundWindow", SetLastError:=True)> _
  Private Shared Function GetForegroundWindow() As IntPtr
  End Function

  <DllImport("aygshell.dll", EntryPoint:="SHFullScreen", SetLastError:=True)> _
  Private Shared Function SHFullScreen(ByVal hwndRequester As IntPtr, _
                                       ByVal dwState As Integer) As Boolean
  End Function

  <DllImport("coredll.dll", EntryPoint:="EnableWindow")> _
  Private Shared Function EnableWindow(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, _
                                       ByVal bEnable As Boolean) As Boolean
  End Function

  <DllImport("coredll.dll", EntryPoint:="FindWindow")> _
  Private Shared Function FindWindow(ByVal lpClassName As String, _
                                     ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
  End Function

  <DllImport("coredll.dll", _
             EntryPoint:="GetForegroundWindow", _
             SetLastError:=True)> _
  Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, _
                                      ByVal Msg As Integer, _
                                      ByVal wParam As Integer, _
                                      ByVal lParam As Integer) As IntPtr
  End Function

  Private Const SHFS_SHOWSTARTICON As Integer = &H10
  Private Const SHFS_HIDESTARTICON As Integer = &H20
  Private Const SHFS_HIDESIPBUTTON As Integer = &H8
  Private Const SHFS_SHOWSIPBUTTON As Integer = &H4
  Private Const SHFS_SHOWTASKBAR As Integer = &H1
  Private Const SHFS_HIDETASKBAR As Integer = &H2

  'Additional variables
  Private Const WM_ENABLE As Integer = &HA
  Private Const CAMERA_INDICATOR As Integer = &H800C 'WM_APP+12
  Private Const CAMERA_ENABLED As Integer = &H1
  Private Const CAMERA_DISABLED As Integer = &H0
  Private Const WM_USER As Integer = &H400
  Private Const WM_ACTIVATE_CAMERAVIEW As Integer = WM_USER + 1
  Private Const WM_CANCELMODE As Integer = &H1F

  Private Shared Function SetTaskBarEnabled(ByVal bEnabled As Boolean) As Boolean
    Dim hwnd As IntPtr = FindWindow("HHTaskBar", Nothing)

    If Not hwnd.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) Then
      If bEnabled Then
        Return EnableWindow(hwnd, True)
      Else
        Return EnableWindow(hwnd, False)
      End If
    End If
    Return True
  End Function

  Private Shared Function SetTaskbarVisible(ByVal visible As Boolean) As Boolean
    Dim hwnd As IntPtr = FindWindow("HHTaskBar", Nothing)

    If Not hwnd.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) Then
      If visible Then
        Return SHFullScreen(hwnd, SHFS_SHOWTASKBAR)
      Else
        Return SHFullScreen(hwnd, SHFS_HIDETASKBAR)
      End If
    End If
  End Function

  Private Shared Function SetStartButtonVisible(ByVal visible As Boolean) As Boolean
    Dim hwnd As IntPtr = GetForegroundWindow()

    If Not hwnd.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) Then
      If visible Then
        Return SHFullScreen(hwnd, SHFS_SHOWSTARTICON)
      Else
        Return SHFullScreen(hwnd, SHFS_HIDESTARTICON)
      End If
    End If
  End Function

  Private Shared Function SetSIPVisible(ByVal visible As Boolean) As Boolean
    Dim hwnd As IntPtr = GetForegroundWindow()

    If Not hwnd.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) Then
      If visible Then
        Return SHFullScreen(hwnd, SHFS_HIDESIPBUTTON)
      Else
        Return SHFullScreen(hwnd, SHFS_HIDESIPBUTTON)
      End If
    End If
  End Function

  Public Shared Sub ShowTaskBar()
    SetTaskBarEnabled(True)
    SetTaskbarVisible(True)
  End Sub

  Public Shared Sub HideTaskBar()
    SetTaskbarVisible(False)
    SetTaskBarEnabled(False)
  End Sub

  Public Shared Sub ShowSIP()
    SetSIPVisible(True)
  End Sub

  Public Shared Sub HideSIP()
    SetSIPVisible(False)
  End Sub

  Public Shared Sub HideStartButton()
    SetStartButtonVisible(False)
  End Sub

  Public Shared Sub ShowStartButton()
    SetStartButtonVisible(True)
  End Sub

  Public Sub MySendMessage(ByVal target As String, _
                           ByVal message As Integer, _
                           ByVal lParam As Integer, _
                           ByVal wParam As Integer)
    Dim hwnd As IntPtr = FindWindow(target, Nothing)
    Dim msg As Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms.Message = Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms.Message.Create(hwnd, message, lParam, wParam)
    MessageWindow.SendMessage(msg)
  End Sub

  'Enables / Disables the camera
  Private Sub btnDisableCam_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDisableCam.Click
    MySendMessage("HHTaskBar", WM_ENABLE, 0, CAMERA_INDICATOR)
    'EnableWindow(WM_ACTIVATE_CAMERAVIEW, False)
    'MySendMessage("HHTaskBar", CAMERA_INDICATOR, WM_ENABLE, CAMERA_DISABLED)
    'MySendMessage("HHTaskBar", WM_ACTIVATE_CAMERAVIEW, WM_ENABLE, CAMERA_DISABLED)
    'MySendMessage("HHTaskBar", WM_CANCELMODE, 0, 0)
  End Sub

  Private Sub btnEnableCam_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEnableCam.Click
    MySendMessage("HHTaskBar", WM_ENABLE, 1, CAMERA_INDICATOR)
    'EnableWindow(WM_ACTIVATE_CAMERAVIEW, True)
    'MySendMessage("HHTaskBar", WM_CANCELMODE, 1, 0)
    'MySendMessage("HHTaskBar", CAMERA_INDICATOR, WM_ENABLE, CAMERA_ENABLED)
  End Sub

End Class`

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Ian

Comment: Why not call the camera function instead of trying to call some wrapper's `Button Click`? This is obviously something specific to a device, so get the device's SDK.

Comment: I wish I could do that. The problem is that the application should be as generic as possible, so making the application too device specific is also not an option. But thanks for the suggestion jp2code! (",)

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about re-enabling the buttons when you need the camera to function properly? then disable the buttons again once the camera function has been completed??

ShowCameraDialog()

- Enable task bar buttons
- Show Camera Dialog
- Dialog Response?.. do stuff with picture..
- Disable task bar buttons again